# django admin registration isn't showing up

Tags: django

I started a django tutorial "http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/photo.html", and have followed the instructions for 2 of their apps and neither is working. I am trying to register these models in admin and all I see on the admin page is "Authentication and Authorization, Groups, Users" stacked on top of each other. Where are my album, tags, and image admins? I ran syncdb before starting runserver

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.model import User

class Album(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    public  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class Image(models.Model)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image       = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
    tags        = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    albums      = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
    created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating      = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    width       = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_field    = ["title"]
    list_display    = ["title"]

class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["tag"]

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields   = ["title"]
    list_display    = ["__unicode__", "title", "user", "rating", "created"]
    list_filter     = ["tags", "albums"]

admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

Comment: what version of django are you using?

Comment: nevermind for now, I have a new error that seems to have a relevant answer on stack. ty